# 'Float'/'int' Object is not callable

Tags: python, float

Estoy programando en `Python` un programa que, dada una lista de vendedores, la sucursal donde trabajan y las ventas, determine que premio le corresponde a cada uno en función de las ventas y se pueda consultar las ventas promedio de alguna sucursal.

Todo funciona **bien** cuando ingreso el primer apellido, pero cuando ingreso las ventas del segundo trabajador, me da **error** al llamar a la función que calcula el premio. Depende de la cantidad de ventas que le ingrese al vendedor, el error dice '`float`' o '`int`'. Espero esto sirva de algo.

Esta función debe estar presente ya que es parte de la consigna del trabajo. Si pudieran ayudarme se los agradecería.

Les dejo el programa para que lo vean. Escribí error en mayúsculas al lado del renglon que me da el error:

```
def premio(ventas,apellido):
global premio
premio=0
if(ventas>60000):
    premio=ventas*0.2
    print(apellido,"recibirá un premio de $",premio)
else:
    if(ventas>30000):
        premio=ventas*0.1
        print(apellido,"recibirá un premio de $",premio)
    else:
        premio=0
        print("las ventas de",apellido,"fueron insuficientes como para recibir premio")
return premio

def vpsucursal(sucursal,ventas):
global ros
global contros
ros=0
contros=0
global sta
global contsta
sta=0
contsta=0
global bsas
global contbsas
bsas=0
contbsas=0
global cor
global contcor
cor=0
contcor=0
if(sucursal=="Rosario"):
    ros=ros+ventas
    contros=contros+1
if(sucursal=="Santa Fe"):
    sta=sta+ventas
    contsta=contsta+1
if(sucursal=="Buenos Aires"):
    bsas=bsas+ventas
    contbsas=contbsas+1
if(sucursal=="Cordoba"):
    cor=cor+ventas
    contcor=contcor+1
return ros
return contros
return sta
return contsta
return bsas
return contbsas
return cor
return contcor

apellido=" "
while(apellido!="ok"):
apellido=str(input("Ingrese el apellido del vendedor: "))
print("Ingrese sucursal donde trabaja",apellido)
sucursal=str(input())
print("Ingrese ventas de",apellido)
ventas=int(input())
p=premio(ventas,apellido)   **ERROR**
sueldo=ventas+p
print("El sueldo de",apellido,"será $",sueldo)
vpsucursal(sucursal,ventas)
z=str(input("¿Terminó de ingresar vendedores? <s/n> "))
if(z=="s"):
    apellido="ok"
for suc in range (4):
x=str(input("¿Quiere consultar las ventas promedio de alguna sucursal? <s/n> "))
if(x=="s"):
    pregunta=str(input("Ingrese sucursal a consultar: "))
    if(pregunta=="Rosario"):
        vpros=ros/contros
        print("Las ventas promedio de la sucursal Rosario fueron $",vpros)
    if(pregunta=="Santa Fe"):
        vpsta=sta/contsta
        print("Las ventas promedio de la sucursal Santa Fe fueron $",vpsta)
    if(pregunta=="Buenos Aires"):
        vpbsas=bsas/contbsas
        print("Las ventas promedio de la sucursal Buenos Aires fueron $",vpbsas)
    if(pregunta=="Cordoba"):
        vpcor=cor/contcor
        print("Las ventas promedio de la sucursal Cordoba fueron $",vpcor)
else:
    break
```

Comment: Bienvenida Valentina a Stack Overflow en español, es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad. ¿Podrías también corregir la identación de tu código? así como está, es irreproducible. Y además, muy importante: agrega el mensaje completo del error, ya que el que pusiste como titulo está incompleto, falta la parte más "jugosa" que permite saber en que parte del script está ocurriendo el error.

Comment: Estaría bien que nos pusieras el log del error también! (copiar/pegar)